# Extracting iPhone Exposure Setting

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Obtaining iPhone Photo Exposure Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373357/obtaining-iphone-photo-exposure-information)

It seems that a similar question has been asked before, [Obtaining iPhone Photo Exposure Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373357/obtaining-iphone-photo-exposure-information)
I wondering with the new iPhone camera, if there is any way to extract exposure data from the camera? it seems that it is able to sample different exposures based on where you focus, but I have yet to find any further documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. It is still not currently available.

Answer (score 0):

Update, so people coming here would know:

- In iOS 4 you can set exposure/white balance/focus to some extent. Basically you can control the mode (auto/continuous/fixed) and the point of interest for these parameters.
- Regardless, if you are capturing still images - you can extract metadata from the image's exif information (actual exposure, shutter speed, iso, etc.)

HTH someone,
Oded